# How can I allow users to make groupings of posts

Tags: user-access

I have a site with many research methods. I want to introduce the abilities for users to create groups of posts and save them for others to access, as a way to make the methods more meaningful for different types of people and applications. Any advice for achieving this. The site is http://www.designmethodsandprocesses.co.uk

I want front end users to do it. The best analogy would be user-generated playlists.

Comment: If I understand correctly just add categories to the posts, that way they are grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to "group" posts are post tags and categories. Both are built in.

Comment: I want front end users to do it. The best analogy would be user-generated playlists.

Comment: @AndrewWelch If it's only for guests (not logged in) you could use a cookie. Everything else is uncontrollable: Bots would try to fire your forms, spammers and kiddies would mess it up for fun, etc. Without a login, you shouldn't do it. If you got a login, you could allow to _choose_ from categories, tags or (a custom taxonomie) terms.

Comment: Yea, I guess I can build a nice interface around this also.